# E/BeaconManager: Cannot contact service to set scan periods

Tags: java, android, ibeacon-android

Hi guys i am using **`android-beacon-library`** and  getting  this message  Cannot `contact service` to set scan periods while start scan  and beacons are not getting scanned.  here is my code `

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();
    AxeltaLogger.debug("Application class on create is called");
    mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(AxeltaBeaconParser.getInstance(context));
    allBeaconsRegion = new Region("AxeltaS7", Identifier.parse("e2c56db5-dffb-48d2-b060-d0f5a71096e0"), null, null);

}

public void startScan() {
    try {
        stopScan();
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, allBeaconsRegion);
        mBeaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(SCAN_PERIOD);
        mBeaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(SCAN_BETWEEN_PERIOD);
        mBeaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(SCAN_PERIOD);
        mBeaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(SCAN_BETWEEN_PERIOD);
        mBeaconManager.setBackgroundMode(true);
    }catch (Exception e){
        AxeltaLogger.err("Error>>>"+e);
    }
}

public void stopScan() {
    if (regionBootstrap != null) {
        regionBootstrap.disable();
        regionBootstrap = null;
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. When using `RegionBootstrap`, you must wait for the first call back to `didDetermineStateForRegion` before setting scan periods or background mode.
2. `RegionBootstrap` is not designed to repeatedly stop and start scanning -- you should not keep constructing new RegionBootstrap instances.  If you do not want scanning to start at app startup, do not use this class.  Instead call `beaconManager.bind(this)` in `onCreate`  and in the `onBeaconServiceConnected` callback set up your scan periods.  You can then  start and stop scanning by calling `startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion` and `stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion`

Comment: thanks for the reply.after removing mBeaconManager.setBackgroundMode(true); its working fine